# zend framework : set imap mail to read, or move it to a folder

Tags: php, zend-framework, imap

After reading a message's state in Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap with $message->getHeaders(). How do I then set that mail as read?

> setHeaders(Zend_Mail_Storage::FLAG_SEEN);

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

```
$imap = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($config);

$imap->setFlags($message_id,array(Zend_Mail_Storage::FLAG_SEEN));
```